# Converting from Gauss-Kruger to Bing coordinates / projection

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, proj, bing-maps

I am trying to convert a shapefile with `ogr2ogr` from Gauss-Kruger (zone 4) to Bings coordinate system / projection using the advice given in http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/the-google-maps-bing-maps-spherical-mercator-projection/:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:31468 -t_srs Bing-Projection.txt out.shp in.shp
```

Where `Bing-Projection.txt` contains

```
PROJCS["Popular Visualisation CRS / Mercator",
 GEOGCS["Popular Visualisation CRS",
  DATUM["WGS84",
    SPHEROID["WGS84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7059"]],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","6055"]],
 PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0, AUTHORITY["EPSG", "8901"]],
 UNIT["degree", 0.0174532925199433, AUTHORITY["EPSG", "9102"]],
 AXIS["E", EAST], AXIS["N", NORTH], AUTHORITY["EPSG","4055"]],
PROJECTION["Mercator"],
PARAMETER["semi_minor",6378137],
PARAMETER["False_Easting", 0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing", 0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian", 0],
PARAMETER["Latitude_of_origin", 0],
UNIT["metre", 1, AUTHORITY["EPSG", "9001"]],
AXIS["East", EAST], AXIS["North", NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3785"]]
```

But I get the following output:

```
ERROR 6: No translation for Mercator to PROJ.4 format is known.
Failed to create coordinate transformation between the
following coordinate systems.  This may be because they
are not transformable, or because projection services
(PROJ.4 DLL/.so) could not be loaded.
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bilke/7942425) for the full output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use directly the EPSG code of Web Mercator (`EPSG:3857`):

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:31468 -t_srs EPSG:3857 out.shp in.shp
```

The content of your `Bing-Projection.txt` file should be in Proj.4 format:

```
+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```